# Fetching Results with datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, mktime

I'm trying to fetch results between two time intervals. I've done this before with another web app I built using just `Y-m-d`, but now having problems with `Y-m-d H:i:s`. The code is below (masked of-course for security reasons):

```
$m5b = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(0,0,0,0,0,0,date('Y'),date('m'),date('d'),date('H'),date('i')-5,date('s')));
$npm = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(0,0,0,0,0,0,date('Y'),date('m'),date('d'),date('H'),date('i')+1,date('s')));
$gm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acm WHERE lgt !='0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND logged BETWEEN '$m5b' AND '$npm'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously recommend reading up on PHP's `strtotime()` function and if you're using a recent version of PHP5 then the DateTime object. This should clean up your code no end.

With strtotime()

```
$t = strtotime('+5 mins');
$mysqlFormatted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t);
```

With the DateTime class

```
$t = new DateTime();
$t->modify('+5 mins');
$mysqlFormatted = $t->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank You! strtotime COMPLETELY slipped my mind. I don't know why I didn't use strtotime function like I did before on another project. Thanks :) Also, I just learned something new. I didn't know you could use +5 mins like that. I usually do it in a longer way. I always learn something every day.

Answer (score 1):

seems to me that you are passing way too many parameters to mktime() you are passing 12 params?

Edit:
Using the code from oblig's answer it actually should be:

```
$m5b = date("Y-m-d H:i:s" , (time() - (5*60)) ); // 5 mins in seconds
$npm = date("Y-m-d H:i:s" , (time() + (1*60)) );
```

Comment: Yup: `Warning: mktime() expects at most 7 parameters, 12 given`

Comment: Ok. So I would use this. date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(date('Y'),date('m'),date('d'),date('H'),date('i'),date('s'))); which does this 2011-04-11 14:04:11. Now the problem is that it's not giving the correct time and it also keeps adding more time each load from what I see from the echo.

Comment: the code you just posted is incorrect as well, please look at the php manual or the comment below to see the correct sequence of parameters for the mktime function. I think what oblig suggests in his answer is a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

mktime according to php.net:

```
   int mktime (    
    [ int $hour = date("H") 
    [, int $minute = date("i") 
    [, int $second = date("s") 
    [, int $month = date("n") 
    [, int $day = date("j") 
    [, int $year = date("Y") 
    [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )
```